# how to automate third-party payment page inside hybrid application using appium?

Tags: appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to automate a Hybrid application using Appium , the application is using a third party payment gateway, so it opens their page in a webview when the user has to pay using a VISA card. the driver is not able to get the page source for the payment page.

Comment: I got the URL of the driver and it is showing the URL of the application instead of showing the URL of the payment page, so the question is how could I make the driver detect the newly opened page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the app is opening another window , that is why I am not able to capture it, so in order to capture it , you need to loop through all windows and ensure that the currently used window is the desired one by checking the existed elements.
here is the code in C#

```
            foreach (var Wind in Setup.driver.WindowHandles)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Window name is " + item );
                Setup.driver.SwitchTo().Window(item);
                Console.WriteLine(Setup.driver.Url);                    
                var Condition= Setup.driver.FindElements(By.XPath
                ("//button[contains(.,'Pay')]")).Count;
                Console.WriteLine(x);
                if (x == 1)
                {  
                    break;
                }
```